# Find the multiplicative inverses of each nonzero element of the field $Z/(5), Z/(11), Z/(17).$

Tags: abstract-algebra, equivalence-relations

For $Z/(5)$, I figured that $[4]$ is a class that has an inverse of its own since $4 \equiv -1 (mod 5)$. Is that correct? Then I tried figuring that $[2]$ is also an inverse of its own since $2 \equiv -3 (mod5)$. Am I doing this correctly?

Comment: $[3]$ is the inverse of $[2]$.

Comment: Is that because $[2] * [3] = 6 \equiv 1(mod5)$? In that case, there are no other inverses for $[5]$ because there are no nonzero elements that can create a $11 \equiv 1 (mod5$). Wouldn't $[4]$ be an inverse of itself since $[4] * [4] = 16 \equiv 1 (mod5)$?

Comment: Yes, that's right. $[0]$ of course does not have an inverse, and $[4]$ is its own inverse, as is $[1]$.

Comment: Do the products of the elements must $ = +/-1$?

Comment: $[b]$ is the inverse of $[a]$ if and only if $ab\equiv 1\pmod{5}$ (similar for other moduli).

Comment: Only positive $1$? Could it also be for $-1$?

Comment: Just $1$, not $-1$, except in the very special case $p=2$, where $[1]=[-1]$.

Comment: Now tell me the inverses of $[1],[2],[3],\dots,[10]$ modulo $11$.

Comment: $[1]$ itself, $[2]$ is the inverse of $[3]$, $[3]$ is the inverse of $[4]$, $[5]$ is the inverse of $[9]$, $[7]$ is the inverse of $[8]$. Can the elements be interchangeable? Instead of saying $[2]$ is the inverse of $[3]$, can I say $[3]$ is the inverse of $[2]$,

Comment: Modulo $11$, $[1]$ is its own inverse, $[6]$ is the inverse of $[2]$, and $[2]$ is the inverse of $[6]$, $[4]$ is the inverse of $[3]$, and $[3]$ is the inverse of $[4]$, and so on, until finally $[10]$ is its own inverse.

Comment: Why is $[10]$ is its own? BTW, isn't $[7]$ and $[8]$ inverses of each other?

Comment: Yes, you had mentioned that and it was right so I did not repeat it. As to $10$, we have $(10)(10)=100\equiv 1\pmod{11}$. Instead of calling it $[10]$ we could call it $[-1]$.

Answer (score 1):

As $5,11$ and $17$ are prime, every non-zero element of $\Bbb Z/p$ will have an inverse.

$1$ and $-1$ are always self-inverse and (for primes $>3$) the other numbers form pairs of inverse elements. As there are only two elements remaining in $\Bbb Z/5$, the inverse table  is simple:

\begin{array}{c|l}
a & a^{-1} \quad (\Bbb Z/5) \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 \\
3 & 2 \\
4 & 4 \\
\end{array}

Some inverses for $\Bbb Z/11$ are easy because $11+1$ has small factors and given $a^{-1} = b$ then $(-a)^{-1} = -b$ (although when $p\equiv 1 \bmod 4$ there will be one pair for which $b = -a$)

\begin{array}{c|l}
a & a^{-1} \quad (\Bbb Z/11) \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 6 \quad (\text{from }12/2)\\
3 & 4 \quad (\text{from }12/3)\\
4 & 3 \\
5 & 9 \quad (\text{from }\{-6,-2\})\\
6 & 2 \\
7 & 8 \quad (\text{from }\{-4,-3\})\\
8 & 7 \\
9 & 5 \\
10 & 10 \\
\end{array}

Then $\Bbb Z/17$ starts to become a little more work.

\begin{array}{c|l}
a & a^{-1}\quad (\Bbb Z/17) \\ \hline
1 & 1 \\
2 & 9 \quad (\text{from }18/2)\\
3 & 6 \quad (\text{from }18/3)\\
4 & 13 \quad (\text{from }4^2\equiv -1 \Rightarrow \{4,-4\}) \\
5 & 7 \quad (\text{from }35/5)\\
6 & 3 \\
7 & 5 \\
8 & 15  \quad (\text{from }\{-9,-2\})\\
9 & 2 \\
10 & 12  \quad (\text{from }\{-7,-5\})\\
11 & 14  \quad (\text{from }\{-6,-3\}\\
12 & 10 \\
13 & 4 \\
14 & 11 \\
15 & 8 \\
16 & 16 \\
\end{array}

And for larger values of $p$ inverses in $\Bbb Z/p$ might better be worked out as required with some version of the extended Euclidean algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

to find multiplicative inverses for a nonzero elements in field
${\mathbb{Z}_p}$, as for any
$a \in {\mathbb{Z}_p}$
find

$b \in {\mathbb{Z}_p}$ such that

$ab \equiv 1\left( {\bmod p} \right)$

Example,in the field ${\mathbb{Z}_5}$

[\begin{gathered}
  1 \cdot 1 \equiv 1\left( {\bmod 5} \right) \\ 
  2 \cdot 3 = 6 \equiv 1\left( {\bmod 5} \right) \\ 
  4 \cdot 4 = 16 \equiv 1\left( {\bmod 5} \right) \\ 
\end{gathered} ]

then, the inverse of 1 is 1, inverse 2 is 3, inverse of 3 is 2 and inverse of 4 is 4.

I hope, it may be some helpful